# How to serve new public assets in production?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.6

My Play application generates some files at runtime and I would like to be able to access those files as public assets.

I tried to place them in the public folder, which is served by

```
GET    /assets/*file    controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

but I'm not able to get these files. It seems that the server is only able to serve the files that have been packaged during the build.

I also tried to add the following lines in build.sbt as suggested in another post:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.MappingsHelper._
    mappings in Universal ++= directory(baseDirectory.value / "public")
```

with this I can see all the packaged assets in the public folder, but still the server does not serve new files added at runtime.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Playframework packs the public folder to the `jar` file and use it while serving assets. So you are not able to add something here at runtime.

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/AssetsOverview#How-are-public-assets-packaged?

> during the build process, the contents of the public folder are processed and added to the application classpath.
>
> When you package your application, all assets for the application, including all sub projects, are aggregated into a single jar, in target/my-first-app-1.0.0-assets.jar. This jar is included in the distribution so that your Play application can serve them. This jar can also be used to deploy the assets to a CDN or reverse proxy.

You need to create file uploader (you already did it) and "file controller" aka "assets controller." Something like

```
def file(name: String) = Action {
  Ok.sendFile(new java.io.File("/uploaded/" + name))
}
```

More here: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaStream#Serving-files